# Speed up Venus using radiation pressure from the sun?

Tags: terraforming, radiation, planets

The amount of energy required to change the rotational velocity of Venus in any meaningful way is immense. Requiring far more energy than humanity can muster at the present date. But I wonder if we can use the most powerful thing in our solar system, the sun, to affect the Venutian rotation? Can we turn Venus into a radiometer?

Would the rotational velocity of Venus change if we shaded half of the planet? Shade the half rotating toward the sun and only allow sunlight to strike the half rotating away from the sun? Would the radiation pressure of the sun on the lighted half help to increase the rotational velocity of the planet? And if so, how long would it take for the rotation to match that of Earth?

Comment: Apparently [this would work for changing orbital velocity](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26131/why-paint-only-one-half-of-bennu). I'm not sure how you would change *rotational* velocity, though.

Comment: No time for a full answer now, but how is the shading happening?  Putting a sunshade in orbit would require stationkeeping drives which would use _at least_ as much energy as would be imparted to the unshaded side of Venus, by necessity (since it would be encountering the same amount of radiation pressure as the unshaded side of the planet).  Thermodynamics being the cruel mistress it is, that would seem like something of a waste of energy.

Comment: It's essentially a huge solar sail, I'd imagine you could reflect the light in such a way (multiple directions, not simply a flat plane) as to maintain proper positioning.

Comment: @jdunlop I can't remember where, but I believe I've seen a strategy for using multiple mirrors to help counteract that radiation pressure... I'll look around and see if I can find it again.

Comment: If you're blocking the light from impacting half the planet, though, the vector sum would still push the sail towards the planet, I'd think.

Comment: @jdunlop it'll push the sail away from a gravitational orbit, but combining gravity and photon pressure, you could maintain position. However, it'd probably be a lot more effective to turn NEOs into many, many sailcraft and have them impact Venus at the appropriate angle (perhaps coming in retrograde for higher impact velocity). It would take a huge number of sailcraft and be abominably expensive and wasteful of material, but might actually get the job done in less than a few million years. Then you just need statite shades for climate control...and everything else needed to terraform Venus.

Answer (score 6):

This would be difficult to do, but it's easy to make an order-of-magnitude estimate of *how* difficult it is. We can estimate the angular acceleration this would produce on Venus by [calculating the radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure#Pressures_of_absorption_and_reflection) at its orbit, in an ideal scenario:
$$P_{\text{rad}}=\frac{2G_{\text{SC}}}{c}\left(\frac{r}{\text{AU}}\right)^2\approx1.74\times10^{-5}\text{ Pascals}$$
with $G_{\text{SC}}$ the solar constant and $r$ the orbital radius of Venus. The force is then $P_{\text{rad}}$ multiplied by half of the cross-sectional area of Venus:
$$F=P_{\text{rad}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}R^2\approx10^9\text{ Newtons}$$
We can estimate the torque applied to Venus by $\tau\approx F\cdot(R/2)$ and calculate the angular acceleration by dividing this by the moment of inertia, giving
$$\alpha\approx\frac{\frac{1}{2}FR}{\frac{2}{5}MR^2}\approx4.24\times10^{-23}\text{ radians s}^{-2}$$
Venus currently has a rotation speed of $\omega=3\times10^{-7}\text{ radians s}^{-1}$, so you'd need timescales of
$$\Delta t=\frac{\omega}{\alpha}\approx300\text{ million years}$$
to make any significant change.

Comment: Unless we somehow lens the radiation instead of blocking half of it... then it's only 150 million years :P

Comment: I would add earth rotation velocity as well, 0.000072 rad/sec, hm around 50 billion years, hm surprisingly fast. Also this has effect on comets asteroids, it has some wiki article but forgot the name of the effect, it more about rotating ones for which one side is emitting more IR than  the another one.

Comment: Only six orders of magnitude to go in order to get that time scale down to 300yrs!
We could of course gather more sunlight with reflection to increase the effectiveness and lower the time scale.

Comment: @loweryjk Yeah, reflection or lensing, like Corey suggested, would be interesting. With the time required inversely related to the flux or area the light is incident upon, it looks like (running the numbers) you'd need to absorb about 0.1% of the total light of the Sun and funnel it onto half of Venus in order to get the timescale down to ~300 years. On the other hand . . . the planet would certainly heat up. Although given how hellish it is already, maybe that wouldn't be a huge loss. . .

Comment: @HDE226868 - at six orders of magnitude more energy, I rather suspect "heat up" is an understatement.